# get array of php function call with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am working with php and call a php function with ajax:

```
<button onclick="loop()">Do It</button>

function loop() {
  $.get("ajax.php", {
     action: "true"
   },
   function(result) {
      $("input").val(result);
   });
}
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_GET["action"])) {     
   for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
      $array[] =  array( "Value 1", $i  );
   }
   echo $array;
}
```

My Input value will show this:

[image]

Now I would like to show the first array element.
I modify the code like this:

```
 $("input").val(result[0][0]);
```

My result:

[image]

But it has to be "Value 1"

Here is an overview of my array structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Value 1
            [1] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Value 1
            [1] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Value 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Value 1
            [1] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Value 1
            [1] => 4
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to return a format that javascript understands like JSON.

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

Then jQuery has a convenience method to automatically parse the returned JSON string:

```
$.getJSON("ajax.php", ...
```

Now `result` will be a javascript array in your ajax response.